# Replace all with passing parameter in Intelij

Tags: intellij-idea

I must update Primefaces version in my project, and I must change elements like

```
#{p:component('string')}
```

to

```
#{p:resolveFirstComponentWithId('string', view).clientId}
```

It's possible to do it in Intelij?
I think I should use replace all by regex, but how to pass componentId parameter between this two expressions?

Comment: You could try using Structural Search and Replace feature - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html#structural_replace .